# How to use generic "analytical.*" tags in django-analytical

Tags: django, google-analytics

I try to setup Google Analytics with django-analytical for my django project, following this guide: http://pythonhosted.org/django-analytical/services/google_analytics.html#google-analytics-configuration.

In this guide you can find the following statement :
"Next you need to add the Google Analytics template tag to your templates. This step is only needed if you are not using the generic analytical.* tags. If you are, skip to Configuration."

So my question is: Where to put this generic analytical.* tag? Is it somewhere in my settings.py file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are planning to use Google Analytics as your service, you can simply add the following to your templates/base.html:

```
{% load google_analytics %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>My Website: {{ title }}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    {% block css %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/main.css">
    {% endblock css %}


    <!--  fix so that IE 9 and less will properly recognize html5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    {% google_analytics %}
</head>
```

See the documentation at: https://pythonhosted.org/django-analytical/services/google_analytics.html

I believe that the generic analytical.* tags that they refer to at the link that you posted have to do with using the following below. If I'm incorrect, others please chime in and provide the correct response. HTH.

```
{% load analytical %}
<!DOCTYPE ... >
<html>
    <head>
        {% analytical_head_top %}

        …

        {% analytical_head_bottom %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% analytical_body_top %}

        …

        {% analytical_body_bottom %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The last paragraph is the correct answer. This is meant by "generic" tags. Using the template code above tracking code is inserted automatically for each service you specify by one of the settings values listed in the [analytical documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/django-analytical/install.html#enabling-the-services), e.g. `GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID = 'UA-1234567-8'`

Comment: Yes, the docs say you can just use `{% load analytical %}` etc., but I am not seeing this working -- nothing gets added to the HTML output even after I set `GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID`